# using NSURL class refrence to view videos in my app from video app

Tags: ios, ipad, video, local, nsurl

I have videos in my ipads local video library. When I click a video in the app I created, the video opens in the local video library not in the app. Does anyone know how i can get the videos to play in the app from the local video library? using NSURL class reference

I've spoken to most of the developers I know & they tell me its not possible. I feel like if there's a will there's a way with a little help :)

Comment: only person that could fix my problem, here visit tip.tempel.org